# In my PayPal server side integration, the payment popup immediately closes. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, django, paypal

I'm trying to setup paypal server side integration, but I keep stumbling on what is likely a very simple issue. **The paypal payment browser window briefly appears to be loading, but it closes before I can do anything; it doesn't reach the login page or anything.** In my django logs, I don't see any errors. Similarly, nothing stands out to me when I search the network activity. If I use a direct link to the paypal authorization page, I don't have any issues.

[image: PayPal Loading]

**Views.py**

```
def setUpAuthorization(request, max_price = 100):
    environment = SandboxEnvironment(client_id = settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
    , client_secret = settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET)
    client = PayPalHttpClient(environment)

    # get_item
    request = OrdersCreateRequest()
    
    # Make initial authorization
    request.request_body(
        {
            "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
            "application_context": {
              "return_url": "https://www.example.com",
              "cancel_url": "https://www.examples.com",
            },

            "purchase_units":[
                {    
                    "description": "DESCRIPTION",
                    "amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",

                        "value": max_price,

                    },
                }
        ]}
    )
    
    response = client.execute(request)
    data = response.result.__dict__['_dict']
    links = data['links']
    for link in links:
        if link['rel'] == 'approve':
            paypal_link = link['href']
    # redirect(paypal_link)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**html**

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id={{client_id}}"> 
  </script>


<script>
    var CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>

<script>       
         function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
</script>

<a href="{% url 'paypal:set-up-authorization' %}">test</a>
<script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch("{% url 'paypal:set-up-authorization' %}", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                });
            },

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have a bad string in the body of CreateOrder API. Please find the below screenshot where you have added extra comma notations.

Also, attached the right JSON string to refer and it worked well for me.

```
{
        "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
        "application_context": {
          "return_url": "https://www.example.com",
          "cancel_url": "https://www.examples.com"
        },
        "purchase_units":[
            {    
                "description": "DESCRIPTION",
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",

                    "value": max_price
                }
            }
    ]
```

}

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The button worked for you after you made these updates? I am still having the same issue where the popup opens, appears to be loading, then closes.

Comment: It does work for me still, could you post down the JSON body here to refer.